# Python / Kivy: How to change the orientation of the list creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've created a responsive list of widgets, but every new item is added at the bottom. I read the documentation, looked for information on the Internet, but I did not find anything, my last hope is you)

It looks like this:

```
v
v
v
|
|
|Element 5 
|
|Element 6
|
|Element 7
|
v
v
v
```

And I want each new element to be created on top of the others.

That is, like this:

```
^
^
^
|
|
|Element 7 
|
|Element 6
|
|Element 5
|
|Element 4
|
|Element 3
|
|Element 2
|
^
^
^
```

in short, I need everything the same but in reverse.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 400)


Builder.load_string('''
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'

<Label@Label>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'

<TextInput@TextInput>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    padding_y: 3


<Row>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 40

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200

    Button:
        text: 'World 1'
        width: 300

<Rows>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"

<User>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 5


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            #padding : 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size: 450, 40
            size_hint: None, None

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "Test 1"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Test 2"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'


        ScrollView:
            Rows:
                id: rows


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .2
            size_hint_y: .2

            Button:
                text: "+Add More"
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 5
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .35
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
            ''')

class User(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('Demo.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add_widget()` method allows for an `index` argument that indicates where in the list of children that the new widget should be placed. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.add_widget). So you can just use tht `index` argument to do what you want:

```
    self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)), index=self.row_count-1)
```